# How to fix "Component for route HomeScreen must be a react component "

Tags: react-navigation

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator( { 
Home : HomeScreen, }, ); 
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

export default class App extends React.Component { render() { return ; } }

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your tag specifies `react-native-navigation` which is different from `react-navigation`. You are using `react-navigation`. here is your solution:

```js
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer / > ;
  }
}
```